Customize QLineEdit
I want to modify QCompleter's default Behaviour of updating suggestions into Qlineedit, I want instead of updating it on Qlineedit it passes that value to a function and then removes all special characters from it and updates that text on Qlineedit
When you run this Code and enter B in the QLineedit It will show you a suggestion and when you press the down arrow it prints you wrong input because it emits an inputRejected signal because it has a special character in it and when we press enter it will update the suggestion in QlineEdit I don't want to set it on Qlineedit
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QCompleter
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QRegExp
from PySide2.QtGui import QRegExpValidator
import random
import string
from functools import partial

def remove_special_characters(text):
    # Remove special characters
    return ''.join(e for e in text if e.isalnum())

class CustomCompleter(QCompleter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def setModel(self, model):
        super().setModel(model)

    def splitPath(self, path):
        # Override the default behavior to return the full path
        return [path]

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        suggestions = ["Apple", "Ban@ana", "Cherry", "Durian", "Elderberry"]
        completer = CustomCompleter(suggestions, self)
        completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        completer.highlighted.connect(self.on_completer_highlighted)
        self.lineEdit.setCompleter(completer)

        # Set validator to allow only alphanumeric characters
        regex = QRegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9_]+")
        self.validator = QRegExpValidator(regex)
        self.lineEdit.setValidator(self.validator)

        # Connect the inputRejected signal
        self.lineEdit.inputRejected.connect(self.wrong)

    def on_completer_highlighted(self, text):
        random_text = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=8))
        print("Random text:", random_text)
        self.lineEdit.setValidator(None)  # Temporarily disable validator
        QTimer.singleShot(
                    1, partial(
                        self.lineEdit.setText,
                        "UUUUU",
                    )
                )
        

    def process_text(self, text):
        cleaned_text = remove_special_characters(text)
        print("Cleaned suggestion:", cleaned_text)
        self.lineEdit.setText("cleaned_text")

    def wrong(self):
        print("Wrong input")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


Sorry but your problem is unclear, and we also don't answer to questions that don't show actual research and attempt efforts. Did you actually try to do what you want? If so, please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] of your attempts. If not, then do some research on how QLineEdit works and do try to make what you need, then, in case you fail or you're unsatisfied with the result, provide a MRE as written above.

Thanks for the update. Can you be more clear about the special behavior you're looking for? Your example is a bit confusing, since you're setting a validator that prevents characters in the suggestion list, so one could actually update the line edit with invalid characters (as long as they are selected from the suggestion), which is a bit confusing.
